# Trying to scrape a website using Python, LXML, PyQt - Getting wierd results

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, lxml, screen-scraping

So using code shown in https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/ I'm trying to retrieve the euro value from this link https://btcdirect.eu/nl-nl

But this is the result im getting: [u'1 BTC\xa0', u'\n\t            ?\xa00,00\n            ']

Can anyone help me out?

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from lxml import html

#Take this class for granted.Just use result of rendering.
class Render(QWebPage):
  def __init__(self, url):
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QWebPage.__init__(self)
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
    self.app.exec_()

  def _loadFinished(self, result):
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()
    self.app.quit()

url = 'https://btcdirect.eu/nl-nl'
r = Render(url)
result = r.frame.toHtml()
#This step is important.Converting QString to Ascii for lxml to process
archive_links = html.fromstring(str(result.toAscii()))

#QString should be converted to string before processed by lxml
formatted_result = str(result.toAscii())

#Next build lxml tree from formatted_result
tree = html.fromstring(formatted_result)

#Now using correct Xpath we are fetching URL of archives
archive_links = tree.xpath('//*[@id="bitcoinkoers"]/strong[1]/text()')

print archive_links
```

Comment: I guess you're getting what you asked for :<div id="bitcoinkoers">
            <strong class="ng-cloak">1 BTC&nbsp;<span>=</span>
             &euro;&nbsp;{{exchangeRate | number:2}}
            </strong>

Comment: Is there any way for me to retrieve the actual euro value?